# delay camera xna

Tags: xna, c#, camera

I read this tutorial http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2/Camera_delay.php
but i didnot unsterstand it. Is there another way to delay the camera position movement without this Quaternion and the "up position"?
Basically i want the camera move slowly to another location, and i tried this:

```
        view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraTarget, Vector3.UnitY);
        cameraTarget = position;
        cameraPosition = Vector3.Lerp(new Vector3(0,8,15), world.Backward * 15,1f);
```

i want the camera be 15 units from an object, and move slowly until it will be behind it, but this code dosen't work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that world.Backward is a constant this line of code is going to return the same value every time.

```
cameraPosition = Vector3.Lerp(new Vector3(0,8,15), world.Backward * 15,1f);
```

You want to lerp between the current location and target location.

```
cameraPosition = Vector3.Lerp(cameraPosition, goalPosition, 0.1f);
```

Lerp is the interpolation function below so if value1 and value2 are the same frame after frame then returned value will never change.

```
cameraPosition = value1 + (value2 - value1) * amount
```

Also you want a value less than between 0 and 1. Ex you value of 1.0f gives you. a value of .5 will move you half way to value2 in one tick. A value of .1 will move you a tenth of the way to value2. Below is why 1.0f is a bad weight.

```
cameraPosition = value1 + (value2 - value1) * amount
cameraPosition = value1 + (value2 - value1) * 1
cameraPosition = value1 + value2 - value1
cameraPosition = value2
```

Comment: I know the lerp function and how it works, but I dont know exactly what to do to move the camera position to behind the object

Comment: cameraPosition = Vector3.Lerp(cameraPosition, desiredPosition, 0.1f);

Comment: I did that, and its not working

Comment: @user1202920 I'm afraid you *don't* appear to know how Lerp works, the third parameter is how far between the two points you want the result, `Vector3.Lerp(new Vector3(0,8,15), world.Backward * 15,1f);` is the same as `world.Backward * 15`

Comment: @DanielCarlsson please be nice.